# Matching 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. results for a excel table

Tags: arrays, excel

My wife asked me to assit her with some data of medical nature. Let's start with the kind of data we're working with.

We have multiple csv files and one xlsx file. The xlsx has some personal information (name, addres and unique ID number to name a few). The csv files have results for all of the people. It's clear to me, that those were added by software by simple append to the end of the file. So the person A can have multiple entries there. Each entry would have that unique ID number, as well as the date of when test was done, it's result and the kind of the test. Some test are done only once, some are done twice or thrice.

What we want to achieve? We want to attach data grom csv to the data from xlsx as consecutive columns. Columns like: date of test 1 (done for the 1st time, call it 1-1), result of test 1-1. date of test 1-2, result of test 1-2, date of test 1-3, result of test 1-3, date of test 2, result of test 2 etc...

[I've done a simple spreadsheet to show you, what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrB4d.jpg). (English isn't my native, so that might be why I have trouble googling correct phrases).

What I've been able to manage to do so far (with a little help of google) is:

=SMALL(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F5,A:A,0),0),ROWS($A$1:A1))

Where:

- Column A has names
- Column B has the dates of test
- Column C has info, what procedure was done (but not if for the 1st, 2nd or 3rd time - this has to be determined based on column B. I know, that for this one there is a maximum of 3 tests done for each person)
- Column D has the result (on a screenshot I just used random numbers)

My formula does find the "first" date. From there with formulas including Match or Index it should be relatively easy to fetch the result from the column that is offset from the result in that same row. But before I get there - I need to figure it out for all n-th occurances.

If necessarry, it's easy enough to "split" the csv by the test done, so ex. if there were 3 of those done, we can have 1 csv file split into 3 sheets. I have actually done it already, just as additional way to store this "information", as it may be easier.

Hope I've described my case well enough. If there is some clarification required, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

As it is typically, there are many ways to achieve this. First though, consider adding the CSV to a table in the sheet. This table will be the database to report off of. Also, I am going by the premise that there can be many different types of procedures, not just three as shown in your sheet. The xls looks like there are five. But if the list can grow of procedures the report will have an unmanageable number of columns so rethinking the report format might be a good idea and is the approach I am showing.

[image]

Without writing a single formula you can use pivot tables to generate your report:

[image]

The additional fields for the rows.

[image]

I unchecked the boxes for totals

You can easily filter the table using the filter feature.